# date_format PHP using a mySQL call

Tags: php, mysql, database, date-format

I am having trouble formating the dates that are being returned from my mySQL database. 
Here is the code that I am trying to use:

```
<?php
function get_gold_time()
{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM metal_price WHERE metal= 'GOLD' LIMIT 0, 96"); 


         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

        echo "'" . date_format($result['time'], 'jS ,g A') . "'" . ", " ;  
 } 

         }
?>
```

This is the error I receive:

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in /home/bellsnet/public_html/chart.php on line 128
'',

Without the date format my code looks like this:

```
<?php
function get_gold_time()
{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM metal_price WHERE metal= 'GOLD' LIMIT 0, 96"); 


         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

        echo "'" .$result['time'] . "'" . ", " ;  
 } 

         }
?>
```

And is returning my values as follows:

```
'2011-08-10 01:15:02', '2011-08-10 01:00:02', '2011-08-10 00:45:02', '2011-08-10 00:30:02', '2011-08-10 00:15:02', '2011-08-10 00:00:02', '2011-08-09 23:45:03', '2011-08-09 23:30:02', '2011-08-09 23:15:02', '2011-08-09 23:00:03', '2011-08-09 22:45:02', '2011-08-09 22:40:22', '2011-08-09 22:30:02', '2011-08-09 22:15:02', '2011-08-09 22:13:41', '2011-08-10 02:00:02', '2011-08-10 01:45:02', '2011-08-10 01:30:02', '2011-08-10 02:15:02', '2011-08-10 02:30:02', '2011-08-10 02:45:02', '2011-08-10 03:00:02', '2011-08-10 03:15:03', '2011-08-10 03:30:03', '2011-08-10 03:45:03', '2011-08-10 04:00:03', '2011-08-10 04:15:01',
```

Any Help WOuld be greatly appreciated!  Ive been tinking around with this for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try date()

```
<?php
function get_gold_time()
{
     $goldquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM metal_price WHERE metal= 'GOLD' LIMIT 0, 96"); 


         while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $goldquery )) 
 { 

        echo "'" . date('jS ,g A', strToTime($result['time'])) . "'" . ", " ;  
 } 

         }
?>
```

or use DATE_FORMAT() directly in MYSQL query:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

It would be far better to just format the date in MySQL through DATE_FORMAT() as it would be quite a bit faster and give you what you want.

See this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format